# Python-Selenium page scraping is not working properly

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am simply trying to open a web page through selenium web-driver. Clicks a button on it, interacts with some elements on second page.. etc..

I heard that selenium is best to work with python for this specified purpose so I wrote my code in it which works very fine at once. But gradually day after day the code which was working absolutely fine before ..just stopped working. Stopped interacting with page elements. Every time throw different errors. I am sick of this selenium behavior. Do anyone know why such so happens? Or can u suggest any good alternatives?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
cookie = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Decline')]")
cookie[0].click()
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Search')]")
buttons[0].click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
close = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.close")
close[0].click()
parent = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("job-info")
for link in parent[:19]:
    links = link.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
hyperlink = random.choice(links)
driver.implicitly_wait(150)
driver.find_element_by_link_text(hyperlink.text).click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: In order to help with your errors, you need to provide the traceback of the errors that you're getting, and describe the problem specifically. Otherwise the question is far too broad, there is no way for us to know how to help

Comment: There aren't any specific error. Selenium just don't get able to find that element again,

Comment: There are a number of possible reasons, none of which are due to selenium. It's possible that a site changes paths or element names/IDs, it's possible that your script is being detected and blocked, either selectively or entirely. Are you able to access the site manually? And can you find those same elements in the page source?

Comment: Yes I can find and access too